# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Catch-All Route

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, endpoint

My goal is to redirect any URL request under the website to the default (Index) page. Background, I'm migrating from a multiple page website to a SPA page.

I know how to accomplish with the UseMvc syntax, but how do you do the same with the UseEndpoints syntax?

Currently I have the default syntax that is generated in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I put the following line above app.Endpoints line:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/");
```

And that redirected everything back to the default/root page.